# Load the script from a sub.domain.com on main domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

Is there a way to load on my domain.com the script I have on a sub.domain.com ?
I need to do this somehow without moving the script from the subdomain's folder.

Any way to do this with htacess?

Thanks

Comment: What "script" are you talking about? PHP, JavaScript, bash..?

Comment: with "script" I am reffering to the entire website. It is a Joomla-Virtuemart website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load `domain.com/script` from `sub.domain.com/script`, which is in a subfolder of `domain.com`, you could use

```
Redirect /script /subdomain/script
```

If you want the browser URL remain the same, you must use a `RewriteRule` instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule script subdomain/script
```